# While searching for a record jqgrid showing duplicate entries even if only one record is populating from the Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, struts2, jqgrid

Note that this issue is happening often, i'am using jqgrid for displaying data from database but recently i found that when searching a particular record jqgrid showing duplicate entries with same serial number. I have checked the data populating from the database and found that it only populating a single record. But when it is coming to JQGRID same record is showing two times. My application has built on struts2 and the pagination is server side.

[image]

Comment: Are yuo sure that the server returns only one result? May you post the server response (e.g. the resulting JSON)?

Comment: You didn't show us a code that produces duplicate results. And since it's implemented internally you can't do it. Also you didn't tell about a version of the software are you using, neither a code example that would be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Yeah i'am sure server returns only one result.

Comment: May you give us the resulting JSON?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata i'am trying to replicate the scenario as i mentioned above issue is not showing always.

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Please note that i found that this issue is only replicate in IE. Also note that when ever i put search criteria and press enter key GRIDUTIL function in the struts2 action class getting execute twice. I think this is the reason why JQGRID showing duplicate records. But when i put search criteria and click on the search button by using mouse GRIDUTIL function getting execute only one time, in this case JQGRID not showing duplicate records. I think some problem with my search button.